# How to subset multiple columns with different values of range in R?

Tags: r, subset, slice

I have a dataset `train_cab` with following information:

```
fare_amount pickup_datetime pickup_longitude pickup_latitude dropoff_longitute dropoff_latitude

4.5           1245066981            -73.8            40.7            -73.8             40.7

16.9          1262690536            -74.0            40.7            -74.0             40.8

5.7           1313607900            -74.0            40.8            -74.0             40.8

7.7           1334962842            -74.0            40.7            -74.0             40.8

5.3           1268101260            -74.0            40.8            -74.0             40.8

12.1          1294287645            -74.0            40.7            -74.0             40.8

7.5           1353423900            -74.0            40.8            -74.0             40.8

16.5          1325677920            -74.0            40.8            -74.0             40.8

15.0          1354520400            -74.0            40.7            -74.0             40.7

8.9           1251834060            -74.0            40.7            -74.0             40.8
```

I want to slice it and use particular values only coming in the ranges;
I used below code to subset it:

```
subset(train_cab, (fare_amount >= 2.50 & fare_amount<=600))
subset(train_cab,(pickup_latitude >= -73.00 & pickup_latitude <= 74.83)) 
subset(train_cab,(dropoff_latitude >= -73.00 & dropoff_latitude <= 74.83))
subset(train_cab,(pickup_longitude >= -74.025 &  pickup_longitude <= 74.930))
subset(train_cab,(dropoff_longitude >= -73.00 & dropoff_longitude <= 74.83))
subset(train_cab,(passenger_count >= 1 & passenger_count <= 7))
```

The code execute well without any errors but retrieve a blank dataframe.

Where I am going wrong. I would appreciate the help.

I tried this by assigning to main dataframe as:

```
  train_cab <- subset(train_cab, (fare_amount >= 2.50 & fare_amount<=600))
  train_cab <- subset(train_cab,(pickup_latitude >= -73.00 & pickup_latitude <= 74.83)) 
  train_cab <- subset(train_cab,(dropoff_latitude >= -73.00 & dropoff_latitude <= 74.83))
  train_cab <- subset(train_cab,(pickup_longitude >= -74.025 &  pickup_longitude <= 74.930))
  train_cab <- subset(train_cab,(dropoff_longitude >= -73.00 & dropoff_longitude <= 74.83))
  train_cab <- subset(train_cab,(passenger_count >= 1 & passenger_count <= 7))
```

But this code is removing all the positive values from the latitude and longitude columns.

Comment: I am not able to slice columns in the range @JonSpring How to resolve this ?

Comment: Are you saving the subsetting anywhere? Calling the subset function does not change the `train_cab` object, so the six subsetting actions here don't seem to be changing anything.

Comment: @JonSpring How to save these subsets?

Comment: I presume you're trying to filter one training set to exclude outliers and/or junk data. You could add `train_cab <- ` before each line and running it would then have the effect of overwriting `train_cab` with a dataset that only includes rows matching your conditions.

Comment: Okay I will try

Comment: No, assigning it to is `train_cab` this code is removing all the positive values from the latitude and longitude columns. @JonSpring

Comment: Please include in your question the output of `dput(head(train_cab))` from before any subsetting happens. That will help reduce potential ambiguity about your data and could help diagnose why it's not working the way you expect.